# Update field x from second join error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I want to update a.instit but instead of result i got an error 1064

```
          UPDATE a
          SET a.instit = c.bezeichnung
          FROM kunde AS a
          INNER JOIN bestellte_artikel AS b
          ON a.idkunde = b.idkunde
          INNER JOIN artikel AS c
          ON b.idartikel = c.idartikel
          where 1
```

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SQL-Server syntax, try this :

```
UPDATE kunde  a
INNER JOIN bestellte_artikel  b
 ON a.idkunde = b.idkunde
INNER JOIN artikel c
 ON b.idartikel = c.idartikel
SET a.instit = c.bezeichnung
where 1
```